# PHP Loop with jQuery hide/slide toggle (Repeater field WP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm running a repeater field through WP that repeats the below content. I also have a jQuery bit of code that is set to toggle, how do I make it so not all divs open? As it seems to only be working on the first div.

Is it because it's inside of the loop?

```
<?php if( have_rows('business_dropdown') ) : while ( have_rows('business_dropdown') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <a href="/#/" onClick="submitComment(); return false;" class="AddCityA">
        <?php echo the_sub_field('title'); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="AddCity">
        <?php echo the_sub_field('content'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {   
    $('.AddCity').hide();
    $('.AddCityA').click(function () {
        $('.AddCity').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `$(this).next('.AddCity').slideToggle("slow");`. This will limit it to the next `.AddCity` only.

Comment: Can you submit it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to limit to the next `.AddCity` only, use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {   
    $('.AddCity').hide();
    $('.AddCityA').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.AddCity').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```